# How to make this shape animate up and down?

Tags: css, html

[image: A quadrilateral shape mimicing a garage door]

I am trying to make this shape represent a garage door opening and closing.
Once I have the shape and guidance, I can make the other CSS (width, height, etc) to fit in place

Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems like a "do my work for me" question at the moment...

Comment: Take a look at this http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var closed = false;
    $("#openclose").click(function(){
        if (closed)
            $("#garage").animate({"height": 214, "width": 367}, 1000);
        else
            $("#garage").animate({"height": 10, "width": 367}, 1000);
        closed = !closed;
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/q2534/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this shape using `border`

[Here is the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cwlhz)

HTML

```
<div class="outerWrap">
  <div class="door"></div> 
  <div class="doorLayer"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outerWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.door {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 500px solid #000;
  border-right: 900px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
.doorLayer {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 490px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 890px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 5px;
}
```